# How should I analyze a data set with 1 IV and 2DVs (all scale variables)?

Tags: multivariate-analysis

Hello wonderful statisticians,

I'm writing a proposal for a dissertation where I'd like to look at whether heart rate can predict 1) narrative coherence (as judged on a scale - but could also be categorized), and 2) self-reported relationship satisfaction (also scalar).  Ideally, I'd also like to see if DV1 (narrative coherence) predicts DV2 (relationship satisfaction), as I suspect they're all interrelated.  What's the best way to analyse this data?  Can I analyze DV1 as an IV without compromising the integrity of my analysis?

My thought is to do a MANOVA or MANCOVA.  Any advice, however, would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should really consult with a local statistician who you can discuss the whole project with and spend the time that it really deserves (the length of advice and time lag in the back and forth for a forum like this will not be sufficient).

This could be analyzed using multivariate regression (the regression equivalent of MANOVA, some would consider it a variant of MANCOVA), there could be several regression models whose comparisons would be of interest.  But this also looks like you might be interested in something like Structural equation modeling (SEM) which looks at different types of relationships where 1 variable predicts a second which predicts a third (which may or may not also be directly influenced by the 1st in addition to the indirect relationship).  A Bayesian approach could also model possible relationships between the variables.

There are many other issues that will come up in a good consulting session that are not as easy to get at in an online forum.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'm going to look into these other methods.  For one, I've realized a MANOVA won't work with 3 continuous variables, so I'm starting from the point of a multivariate regression, and will work from there if that is insufficient.